# App42 API Unity SDK: getTinyUrl() return null when using File Upload Service

Tags: unity-game-engine, appwarp, app42

I'm using the **App42 Unity SDK** for uploading binary files; it used to work just fine, but now I've started to get "null" when retrieving the tiny url by calling *fileList[i].GetTinyUrl()*; (just as a documentation shows). The file is uploaded succesfully and only the tiny URL seems to be broken. The regular URL is too long for using in App42 private messages, so it is a blocking issue.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when tiny url service is not available, it might return null, however you can convert it by your own by calling tiny url service from your app.See this tutorial for the same http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-shorten-url-using-tinyurl-service